# How to remove underline from UIBarButtonItem? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, underline

I created a UIBarButtonItem programmatically and the text is underlined. Is there a way to remove the underline?

```
let editButton = UIButton.init(type: .Custom)

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.title = "General Information"
    editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editButtonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    editButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 30)
    editButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: editButton)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(barButtonItem, animated: true)
    updateEditButtonTitle()
    self.navigationController!.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

here is an image of the result I get, with the underline.

[image]

here is the function where I set the button's text.  when it is pressed, it becomes a save button.

```
func updateEditButtonTitle() {
    if let button = self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView as? UIButton {
        var title = ""
        editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.55)
        editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
        if isInEditMode {
            title = "Save"
            editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
            editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
            editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
            editButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 30)
        } else {
            editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
            title = "Edit"
        }

        button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Vang you add a picture to your question

Comment: How did you create the UIBarButtonItem, please show your code so others and I can help you :).

Comment: What is in the `updateEditButtonTitle` function?

Comment: When the Edit button is pressed, it because a Save button.  that is the purpose of that function.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the text for the `editButton` (and the code in that general area)?

Comment: The code shown does not seem like it would create underlined text. Do you use attributed strings anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ..

```
var attrStr: NSMutableAttributedString = yourBtnHere.attributedTitleForState(.Normal).mutableCopy()
//or whatever the state you want
attrStr.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.characters.count), options: .LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, usingBlock: {(attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject], range: NSRange, stop: Bool) -> Void in
    var mutableAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [NSObject : AnyObject](dictionary: attributes)
    mutableAttributes.removeObjectForKey(.AttributeName)
    attrStr.setAttributes(mutableAttributes, range: range)
})
```

With the inspector/IB: Select your UIButton.
Show the Attributes Inspector.
The Text settings should be in Attributed. Select the text, click on the fond item remove the Underlining setting it at none.
enter image description here

[image: Check this]

But..

Let me get this straight. Apple added an accessibility feature that lets users mark buttons with underlines if they want to.

You want a way to defeat this feature, specifically designed to help people with handicaps use their devices, when the feature is something that the user has to ask for.

Why?

It is very likely not possible using standard buttons. If you did figure out a way to do it, Apple would likely reject your app because it defeats a system function meant to help the disabled.

So the answer is: Don't do that.